# How to loading images from firebase storage faster?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I make an app where I have to show profile images and where you can click load more.

I have to load my firebase storage images faster and I don't know how to do that

My code:

```
await FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref('profileImages/${data[i]["uid"]}_profile_picture.jpg')
              .getData();
```

I already tried to compress the image and more things, but I don't know them anymore.

How can I load the images faster?

Comment: Firebase storage is not a CDN. If image load speeds is important for your use case then you should look at using some CDN like [Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn). Also checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68879868

Comment: I don't want to use CDN but thanks

Comment: how long does it take? if its 2-3 seconds its normal, just add a loading animation when u click to download images and remove loading when you have the data, also you can resize the images before upload [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945494/use-html5-to-resize-an-image-before-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945494/use-html5-to-resize-an-image-before-upload) i resize them to 800px and take under 100kb

Comment: hello c0dm1tu I already found a solution and also posted the solution under this question but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem was that firebase storage is too slow.

But I found an easy solution.

---

**Solution:**

You have to make your image into a network image

To do that complete these steps:

**1. Get the URL of the image**

To do that use this code:

```
 var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("profileImages/${uid}_profile_picture.png");
// this is the URL of the image
      String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
```

**2. Save the URL**

If you do it for something like profile images then add the URL to cloud firestore when you add the image and change the image and use this code:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) async {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(value.docs[0].id).update({"profileImageURL": url});
    });
```

If you do it for something like your app icon then use this code:

```
(await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).setString("logoURL", url);
```

**3. Get the URL from an image**

If you use the first way to save the URL(If you do it for something like profile images) then use this code:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
       url = value.docs[0].data()["profileImageURL"];
    });
```

If you do the other way to save the URL(if you do it for something like your app icon) use this code:

```
(await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).getString("logoURL");
```

**4. Display the image**

To display the image use this code:

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  child: Image(image: NetworkImage(url)), 
);
```

---

Hope it helps!